# A question on timers in 8051

Tags: microcontroller, timer, 8051

Suppose the timer 1 of 8051 has finished counting, and raised TF1. Since it rolls back to 0, so currently TH1=00,TL1=00, and assume the bit TR1 is still set. At this moment, if we just clear the TF1 alone , will it count now from 00 again? Because we did not stop the timer yet.

Next question is - let us take TF1 is set but TR1 is reset, at this moment can we load the TH1 and TL1 using # addressing (immediate)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At this moment, if we just clear the TF1 alone , will it count now from 00 again? Because we did not stop the timer yet.

`TF1` will set once the Timer-1 overflows. Now, if you clear `TF1` but keeps `TR1` set, then the timer keeps running.
After the overflow, it will restart incrementing from `0x00` or pre-loaded value in `TH1` (depends on timer mode).

So, in case of *16-bit timer mode*, you have to clear both `TF1` and `TR1`, reload the Timer-1 register, and set `TR1` again to continue the same cycle.

In case of *auto-reload 8-bit timer mode*, clearing `TF1` alone will suffix. No need to clear `TR1` as the timer automatically restarts from the pre-loaded value in `TH1`.

> let us take TF1 is set but TR1 is reset, at this moment can we load the TH1 and TL1 using # addressing (immediate)?

Yea, you can. And once you set `TR1`, timer starts running from the loaded value. But you should clear `TF1` to not miss the event of next timer overflow.

Comment: in the last two lines you said "you should reset TF1...", but it should be "you must reset TF1..'' Isn't it? I think with a raised TF1, the timer won't even start counting even if TR1 is set.

Comment: By 'reset', it means clear. TF1 has to be cleared. not TR1. TR1 set means counter is running regardless of TF1 value. TF1 is not a control flag, it is a status flag. If you forgot to clear TF1, you will miss subsequent timer overflow events, because timer is actually still running inside.